# Parsing long string as datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-dateutil

When using

```
import datetime
s = 'Sat Apr 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100'
print datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a %m %d %y %H:%M:%S GMT+0100")
```

I get:

> ValueError: time data 'Sat Apr 23 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100' does not match format '%a %m %d %y %H:%M:%S GMT+0100'

How to parse such a string?

*Note: Using `dateutil.parser.parse` didn't work : it produced some weird `datetime` object that I could **not** subtract with another datetime, i.e. `d1 - d2` didn't work.*

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't subtract the datetime object from another one? What was the error message? I can't think of any failure mode that would prevent you from subtracting two datetimes.

Comment: Not recommending using the dateutil parser for a known format, but FYI, I suspect the problem is that the parser gives you a timezone aware object. If you want to subtract another datetime, you either want them both to be timezone aware or both be native. Best is to just convert both to UTC for absolute time differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://strftime.org/),
the format should be `"%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT+0100"`

Answer (score 2):

Use this [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) instead: `"%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT+0100"`.

I made two changes:

- Replaced `%m` (Month as a zero-padded decimal number) with `%b` (Month as locale’s abbreviated name)
- Replaced `%y` (Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number) with `%Y` (Year with century as a decimal number)